# how to read lines starting with arithmatic characters in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using readline to read a file, but some of its lines starts with arithmetic characters, readline skips this lines,
any suggestion?

```
with open(path) as program_file:
for line in program_file:
    line = program_file.readline()
    print(line)
```

some of lines are like this:

```
2 4 5
+ 3 #skip this line
_ 5 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the lines starting with characters that's the problems, it's that the `for line in x` and `x.readline` statements both read a line from the file, so you'll probably get alternate lines printed out. Remove the readline!

```
with open(path) as program_file:
    for line in program_file:
        print(line)
```